# RaggedRightParindent also indents caption titles with subcaption package

Tags: koma-script, subcaption, ragged2e

I am using the KOMA-Script class `scrreprt` with the `ragged2e` package to achieve ragged right document text. I still want to retain paragraph indentation (and have no inter-paragraph spacing, i.e., parskip=0), so I set `\RaggedRightParindent{2em}`, but this seems to also affect my float captions when the subcaption package is loaded.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage {mwe}%
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % for creating ragged right edge etc
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}% sets the indent size of the first line
\usepackage{subcaption}% for creating figures in figures

\setcapindent{0em}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\lipsum[11]


  \begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setcapindent{0em}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. }
  \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

How can I get rid of this indentation? (I still want to keep these packages if possible...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the value of `\RaggedRightParindent` to zero for all `figure` and `table` environments by adding the following three lines of code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0em}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0em}}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage {mwe}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\setcapindent{0em}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0em}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0em}}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering 
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  u & v & w\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-3]
```

\end{document}

Comment: Odd, this works for the MWE, but didn't for my larger document. Something else is muddying the waters. I have put `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcapindent{0em}}` as well, and that does it.

Answer (score 5):

Define a caption style:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % for creating ragged right edge etc
\usepackage{caption}% for creating figures in figures

\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}% sets the indent size of the first line

\DeclareCaptionFormat{komaflush}{\noindent\hspace{-\RaggedRightParindent}#1#2#3\par}
\captionsetup{format=komaflush}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\lipsum[11-12]


\begin{figure}[tbh]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown
  fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy
  dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a tidy solution. I get some overlap of figure and caption text when using a `\captionbeside` environment though, any idea why? And where is `\DeclareCaptionFormat` from?

Comment: @adifferentben I don't know about `\captionbeside`; `\DeclareCaptionFormat` is part of `caption`.

Comment: `\captionbeside` is an environment from the KOMA-Script classes. Allows floats to have their captions placed beside them :) It has some additional width and placement options (see page 115 for version 2012-07-22 of the docs).

Comment: @adifferentben I understand it, but I won't try and guess how you're using it.

Comment: @adifferentben My impression is that `\RaggedRight` thoroughly confuses `captionbeside`.